# I Want Using two DbContext asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I want using two datacontext for myapp

```
 services.AddDbContext<AuthenticationContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));

                services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConection"))
                );
```

The DbContextOptions passed to the AuthenticationContext constructor must be a DbContextOptions. When registering multiple DbContext types make sure that the constructor for each context type has a DbContextOptions parameter rather than a non-generic DbContextOptions parameter.'

Comment: Could you please update the question with each DbContext?

Comment: yes i can updata database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use multiple dbcontext in your app, adding new dbcotext is the same to your first dbcontext.

1.Create a dbContext

```
public class DataContext: DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

2.appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "IdentityConnection": "xxx",
    "MyConection": "xxx"
},
```

3.Register the dbcontext

```
 services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConection"))
            );
```

If you would like to add migration,just specify which context you would like to use, for example:

```
Add-Migration init -Context DataContext
Update-Database -Context DataContext
```

Comment: if you're wondering why DbContextOptions<DataContext> isn't working in your solution, make sure you typed DbContextOptions<YourDataContextClassName> ;)

Answer (score 2):

Register your other contexts before the `ApplicationDbContext` / Identity in `Startup.cs`.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>
```